# Removing Preference data when Application killed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, ondestroy, android-ondestroy

In my application i am storing some SharedPreference data.

I have to clear that all stored data when application killed.

So, I have done it in my activity's `onDestroy()` as below :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    if(isBackPressed==0){
        if(Prefrences.checkPref(MyActivity.this,MAIN_PREF)){
            Prefrences.removePref(MyActivity.this,MAIN_PREF);
            Prefrences.removePref(MyActivity.this,PREF_1);
            Prefrences.removePref(MyActivity.this,PREF_2);
            Constant.displayLogE(">>>>>>>>>>","### Prefrence removed ");
        }
        Constant.displayLogE(">>>>>>>>>>","### Destroy activity ");
    }
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Here, I have taken `isBackPressed` because, When onBackPressed called it calles finish() automatically and onDestroy() method calls. So, I have initialized `isBackPressed` to 1 inside `onBackPressed()` method.

It doesn't matter, I just have to remove my prefrence data when app going to be killed. But, the issue is when I killing app, `onDestroy()` methos not calling.

Thanks.

Comment: call finish(); before super.onDestroy();

Comment: if you want the data cleared when the app is killed, then why do you store it at all? why don't you just keep it in the variables, which will be cleared when app is killed?

Comment: @Tufan not worked. I have just changed it. onDestroy() not called. logs not getting insed Android Monitor..

Comment: @VladMatvienko I have to get Lat and Long for particular places when user clicks on NEARME button and display map accordingly. Now, When user comes back from any other activity the map should be loaded according to previous searched location. Thats why... . .. So, have any solutions ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361719/android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the/18361887#18361887

Comment: add a debug point there and check if app is going in that condition

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called/4449988#4449988

Comment: @Tufan as per above commented url : Basically, there's never a guarantee that onDestroy() will be called, and in some cases processes such as your app will be killed directly, bypassing the method call anyway.   So, How can I clear my data when app is going to be killed ?

Comment: i think in your base activity on back pressed method it will surely call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way.

```
public class App extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      doSomeCleanWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, If i take a Static variable with default value 10 in side an Activity and change it to 20, it remains 20 up to ACTIVITY DESTROYED(CHANGE) or up to APP KILLED ?

Comment: ACTIVITY DESTROYED

Comment: So, in my senario of remembering NEAR_ME location its better to use Prefrence instead of Static variables ?

Comment: yes ,or you can use static variables in your application.