# Where is best place to save frequently changing data

Tags: android, android-database

Think of an activity that contains a toggle button and user can frequently change its state and I have to save that state in database . It does not seem rational to save it on every click ! so I decided to save such changes in onStop() of my activity but I'm wondering is this the correct place ? 
what do you suggest for that . thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an image of the lifecycle of activities:

[image: activity lifecycle]

When you save the data in a database in the `onStop()` method, the data is saved when the activity is no longer visible. This is probably what you want.

`onDestroy()` is not the correct place to save the data to the database, because there is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361719/android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the)

You can use `onPause()` as well if you want. For example, when there is a translucent activity opened, `onPause()` is called, but `onStop()` not because the activity is still visible.

Comment: so you suggest onStop() like what I said ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you use onPause() or onStop(), but yeah... onStop() is a common place to update the database