# Android Life cycle

Tags: android

In what cases on Destroy method is not called but application is killed out? I didn't make such situation, but need to do it. So I need to get a situation where on Destroy method will not be called but application will be killed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Activity onDestroy() is not always called and if called only part of the code is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361719/android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the)

Comment: go though to this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508320/5308778](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508320/5308778)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onStop()` will be called every time but `onDestroy()` will not be called if

• User remove application from recent

• User force stop application from app info

• User uninstalls application even if App is in background.

Answer (score 0):

app is running that time you can press home button, check app is running in background that time you can directly kill this app. this scenario onDestroy method didn't call.